# Script runs command fine, but fails when trying to save output to variable

Tags: shell-script, zsh, path, echo

I have a shell script with the following contents. I call it with `./script.sh`. Echo successfully runs, but not when I try to save its output to a variable. The same is true for all commands I've tested so far; `ls`, `pwd`, `node`, etc…

```
#!/bin/zsh

echo foo
# foo

output=$("echo foo")
# command not found: echo foo
```

How come?

**EDIT:** Fix: the last echo is inside a string!

Comment: The only way I'm able to reproduce this is if I quote `echo foo` like:  `output=$('echo foo')`.  Or if I escape the space like `output=$(echo\ foo)`.

Comment: can't reproduce here; do you have something odd in your zsh profile?

Comment: I'm sorry, The last echo _is_ supposed to reside **in a string**.

Comment: running `"echo foo"` would result in a similar error; what's your goal?

Comment: Simply saving the output to a variable. But I see that it being inside a string may be my mistake…

Comment: I think you are confused about what a string is.  `echo foo` is inside **quotes** which is causing it to be _interpreted as a string_.

Comment: Thanks! I've realised that I really jumped the gun on this question, Not really sure why I was so determined it had to be in a string.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you found the issue.  You should quote only the string passed to `echo` and not the entire command itself:

```
output=$("echo foo")
```

Should instead be:

```
output=$(echo "foo")
```

If you want the `output` variable to contain the literal string `echo foo` then you should just set it as:

```
output='echo foo'
```

but could also do:

```
output=$(echo 'echo foo')
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. An additional question; if i replace echo with `node`, which was my initial goal, calling a node-script. I get `command not found: node` despite node being inside my $PATH variable. Which I checked by echoing path from inside the script. Thoughts?

Comment: Without seeing the command you're attempting to execute and your path I can't really speculate.

Comment: `node script.js` succeeds, `output=$(node script.js)` fails. Falls perfectly in line with the question title, actually.

Answer (score 0):

As one might expect commands inside parentheses creates a subshell. But $() is not what you might think. It does not return the output of a command as a string it substitutes the output of a command into the shell. If you want proof try this: `$(echo "echo 123")`

Instead you want to use double quotes to capture it into a string instead of the array (the output split by spaces) being run on the shell.

`output="$(echo foo)"`

Note this isn't an issue specific to zsh it applies to bash as well.